# Возможно ли как-то добавить текст,в строку который ввел пользователь?

Tags: время, haskell, haskell-stack

Вот мой код

```
getDateFromUser :: IO (Either UserError UTCTime)
getDateFromUser = do
   Prelude.putStrLn "Пожалуйста, укажите дату для прогноза в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД:"
   currentTime <- getCurrentTime
   date        <- Prelude.getLine
       let dayFromUser = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%-m-%-d 12:00:00" 
date :: Maybe UTCTime   ....
```

Мне нужно от пользователя получить дату с помощью `getLine`. Потом я это превращаю в `UTCTime`

И мне нужно за пользователя автоматические добавлять значение.
Н:р://

```
 "Пожалуйста, укажите дату для прогноза в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД:"

 2018-10-04
```

Тогда я получаю ошибку.Всё верно.Мне нужно автоматически за пользователя добавить "12:00:00" То есть чтоб пользователь ввел только `2018-10-04` а у меня это было как `2018-10-04 12:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Уберите из формата `12:00:00` или замените `date` на `(date ++ " 12:00:00")`:

```
let dayFromUser = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%-m-%-d 12:00:00" (date ++ " 12:00:00") :: Maybe UTCTime
```